# зацикливание @OneToMany и @ManyToOne

Tags: java, json, hibernate

При запросе в Postman'e

```
personwithcars?personid={personId}
```

Получается цикл:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Eliah","birthdate":"03.08.1995","cars":[{"id":1,"model":"BMW-X5","horsepower":250,"owner":{"id":1,"name":"Eliah","birthdate":"03.08.1995","cars":[{"id":1,"model":"BMW-X5","horsepower":250,"owner":{"id":1,"name":"Eliah","birthdate":"03.08.1995","cars":[{"id":1,"model":"BMW-X5","horsepower":250,"owner":
```

Сущность Car:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.model;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonManagedReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name="car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "model")
    @NotNull
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "horse_power")
    @NotNull
    private Integer horsepower;

    @NotNull
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Person owner;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ownerid")
    private Long ownerId;

    public Long getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(Long ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Car(){}

    public Car(Long id, String model, Integer horsepower, Long ownerId){
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        if(model.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Integer getHorsepower() {
        return horsepower;
    }

    public void setHorsepower(Integer horsepower) {
        this.horsepower = horsepower;
    }

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Сущность Person:

```
package ru.lanit.rest.model;


import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonBackReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name="birthdate")
    @NotNull
    private String birthdate;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Car> cars;



    public Person(){}

    public Person(Long id, String name, String birthdate){
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
        try {
            setBirthdate(birthdate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Person(Long id){
        setId(id);
    }

    public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        sdf.parse(birthdate);
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public Set<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

}
```

Пытался писать свой метод `toString()`, использовать аннотации `@JsonBackReference` и `@JsonManagedReference`, а так же просто `@JsonIgnore`. При последнем список машин не отображается вовсе, а при остальных цикл не пропадает.

Вопрос: как избавится от зацикливания?

Comment: 1. Сделать связь только в одном Энтити. 2. Опытные люди мне советовали что отдавать entity является плохой практикой и посему сказали пиши свои `DTO` и потом преорбазуй энтити в нужную тебе DTO и отдавай клиенту и тогда таких проблем не будет. (на самом деле проблемы с зацикленностью тоже могут быть, но ведь можно создать разные `DTO` под разный ответ)

Comment: да, DTO помог. я вместо Person стал возвращать PersonDTO, в который я загрузил Set<CarDTO>, внутри которых была та информация про машины, которую мне и нужно было показать.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал DTO (Data Transfer Object): закинул переменные, которые необходимо было показать при GET запросе и возвращал этот Объект.